# Converter texto em imagem utilizando Zend Framework

Tags: imagem, zend, conversão-de-tipo

### Dúvida:

---

Existe outra maneira de converter texto em imagem `PNG` que não seja pelo `**ImageMagick**`?
Estamos utilizando o Zend Framework.

---

Instalei o modulo `[Php5-imagick][1]`, mas deu muito trabalho e precisei atualizar muitos módulos do `PHP` e `Apache`, e acredito que não será possível essa instalação nos ambientes de homologação e produção.

//EDIT

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503077/create-transparent-png-with-text-from-scratch-in-php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php

http://www.daftlogic.com/projects-text-to-image.htm

Encontrei essas formas.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem [cinco bibliotecas diferentes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php) para trabalhar com imagens em PHP: Cairo, Exif, GD, Gmagick e ImageMagick. Com certeza alguma delas deve servir a seus propósitos.

O que você pode fazer é utilizar o Composer para adicionar alguma biblioteca de geração de imagens em seu projeto. Isso torna a instalação muito mais fácil e normalmente não precisaria de configurações externas (por exemplo, no Apache).

Comment: Obrigado, mas infelizmente ainda estamos utilizando o zend 1.

Comment: Ontem mesmo eu converti um projeto em ZF1 para utilizar o Composer. O que tive que fazer foi definir manualmente, no composer.json do projeto, que todas as classes estivessem no namespace raiz. Se você precisar de uma ajuda para fazê-lo, é só falar!

Comment: Rodrigo Rigotti, Vi que você comentou a resposta, você consegue me detalhar como realizar este processo de utilizar o Zend Framework 1 com bibliotecas baixadas pelo composer?? Obrigado.

Comment: @Octávio vi a pergunta que vc havia feito e respondi lá. :)